# Are dev_t and ino_t required to be integer types?

Tags: c, posix, standards, libc

The documentation for glibc stays they are integer types (no narrower than unsigned int), but I'm not finding a standards reference that says they have to be an integer type (see also time_t).

So in the end, the question becomes: Is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
struct stat st;

if (stat("somefile", &st) == 0) {
        printf("%ju %ju\n", (uintmax_t)st.st_dev, (uintmax_t)st.st_ino);
}
```

portable.

Comment: "see also time_t" --> In C, `time_t` may be an integer: signed or unsigned (this is uncommon), or floating point type.  I suspect with POSIX, it it limited to signed integer types.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html) standard requires `dev_t` to be an integer type and `ino_t` to be an unsigned integer.

> dev_t shall be an integer type.
>
> fsblkcnt_t, fsfilcnt_t, and ino_t shall be defined as unsigned integer
>   types.

Since `intmax_t` and `uintmax_t` are supposed to be the "greatest width" integers, your code is safe.
Just to be sure in case `st_dev` happens to be negative, you could write it as:

```
    printf("%jd %ju\n", (intmax_t)st.st_dev, (uintmax_t)st.st_ino);
```

Otherwise, your code is safe.

Answer (score 4):

From the [current POSIX specifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html):

> **dev_t** shall be an integer type.
>
> [...]
>
> **ino_t** shall be defined as unsigned integer types