# The st_dev parameter of a stat structure negative value

Tags: c, filesystems, posix

```
    printf("%s:\n", name);
    struct stat buf;
    if(stat(name, &buf) < 0) {
        printf("\tCannot stat it -- errno=%d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("\tDevice ID:\t%ld\n", buf.st_dev);
```

Using cygwin compiler and codeblocks, on Windows 10 the result on the screen is

```
Device ID:      -855345664
```

I've also tried to print the `st_rdev` value for the same structure. Is 0 but I think it is not correct. My file is in `C:` directory and I was expecting the `st_dev` and `st_rdev` fields to store the drive number (A: → 0, B: → 1, etc.). In my case, both `st_rdev` and `st_dev` to be 2.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps relevant: [Are dev_t and ino_t required to be integer types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48169603/are-dev-t-and-ino-t-required-to-be-integer-types)

Comment: not really, I was expecting the value returned to mean something related to the letter of the drive holding the file. I know it can be negative, but what that value is suppose to mean I don't understand

Comment: I meant, the format specifier and the type passed to `printf()` as in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48169793/4142924).

Comment: Using that answer, my output becomes `DEV ID=3439621632` and  `INODE NR=40813871623057592`

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu  From this link from Microsoft  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/stat-functions?view=msvc-160,  `_stat` is being used on Windows. Try with `_stat` structure and `_stat()`  function.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula, I am using cygwin which makes posix available on windows